# Where can I ask a question regarding hardware identification?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

I need help trying to identifying a old vinyl cutter I found at my workplace recently, but haven't the slightest clue as to where I can ask this type of question.

It should be noted that this vinyl cutter is a piece of computing hardware, used to cut sheets of vinyl for making signs, decals and so forth.

An example of a vinyl cutter - https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/FRsAAOSwCF9c8Zj2/s-l300.jpg

Which Stack Exchange site is best suited for asking questions about hardware identification?

Comment: A lot of sites have a kind of *hate* towards identification questions. Not knowing what a vinyl cutter is, did you consider [DIY.se](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @rene I don't think DIY.se would be the right site, as this vinyl cutter is computer related. I think you may know it as a vinyl plotter, or maybe a sign plotter.

Comment: It is maybe wise to include that context info in your question.

Comment: Hmm, various results: https://stackexchange.com/search?q=vinyl+cutter

Comment: A mixed bag of results for sure, but a welcome one. Unfortunately, these links are troubleshooting Vinyl Cutters, not for identifying hardware

Comment: Do you know the brand?  Do you know some identifying number on the machine?  If you know one of those things, you can use Google (or your search engine of choice) to start digging for it yourself.  Posting it without either of those would rely on random chance that someone recognized it and I don't know a site for commercial hardware identification by picture alone.  I would start by finding a model number, manufacturer number, heck maybe even a serial number (though that might not be useful), and a brand then head to your search engine with that.

Comment: Retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Comment: Identification questions tend to be a bad fit simply cause they're not useful for anyone but OP and are really hard to find. Some chatrooms would be a good fit but finding the appropriate one might be tricky. Working out how to get it to work on a PC, modern or otherwise on the other hand might work, *and* you can sneak in "what is it" with how do I use it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/printer : your question is off-topic according to the tag's description but some of the questions listed and upvoted don't respect the tag's description, so it's unclear whether the tag's description is correct. That Stack Exchange website has several identify-this questions as well but not for not for  printers (https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer).

Comment: Thank you. Will look into this further